# Wordpress: Why is custom action not firing?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a form with a submit button. When the button is clicked, I want to fire a custom action.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <form method="post" action="ccs_fetch_list">
        <?php submit_button(); ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || die();

class CcsAdminPage {

    public static function init() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( __CLASS__, 'add_menu' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( __CLASS__, 'load_scripts' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( __CLASS__, 'register_settings' ) );
        add_action( 'ccs_fetch_list', array( __CLASS__, 'fetch_list' ) );
    }

    ...

    public static function cc_fetch_list() {
        // Do form stuff
        wp_die( "We're here." );
    }

}
```

However, when I click the button, WP loads a blank page. Why? The action does not appear to be firing. What do I need to do to ensure the method is called?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotton to use `do_action`.

You need to put `do_action('ccs_fetch_list');` where you want the custom hook execute.

How it is done in wordpress is something like this.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ccs_fetch_list', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ccs_fetch_list', 'my_action' );
```

and handle this using ajax. You can take reference from [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

There are other reference too. You can see [Confused on AJAX submit form through page template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/276960/confused-on-ajax-submit-form-through-page-template)

and [ajax form post submission using wordpress](https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/ajax-form-post-submission-using-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Change your html as below:

```
   <div class="wrap">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ccs_fetch_list">

        <?php submit_button(); ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now in your class, replace:

```
add_action( 'ccs_fetch_list', array( __CLASS__, 'fetch_list' ) );
```

with

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_ccs_fetch_list', array( __CLASS__, 'fetch_list' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ccs_fetch_list', array( __CLASS__, 'fetch_list' ) );
```